# How to conceal a segmentation fault in a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, segmentation-fault, posix, stderr

I use a program that works properly and results in desirable output at the end of its operation with no memory leak or any other specific issue, but then it issues a segmentation fault at the point it exits. I have been trying to hide this harmless but annoying error from the end user when using this program by redirecting the standard error to Null:

```
program options >file 2>/dev/null
```

But this doesn't work and the error shows up in the middle of the script's outputs each time I run the program. What is exactly happening here, and how can I hide the unwanted error? I'm on Yosemite.

Comment: Why do you consider a segfault to be "harmless"?

Comment: The program is not mine, and I have no idea how to fix it. It is one of Sane scanner backends that issues the segfault, and it seems it is due to a marginal incompatibility between the hardware and the driver. I consider it harmless because I have been using the program heavily and it seems all works fine. I don't know if it forks or not, how can I check it? See for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517685/segmentation-fault-by-sane-pixma-backend-on-osx-sane-pixma-5

Comment: Then it's a fork. The program does all it has to do, but then instead of terminating gracefully, it issues a segfault. I am trying to have a look at the code, but given that it is a driver, most probably I won't understand why reading such or such memory address generates a segfault. I just installed Linux to see if the driver is faulty on Linux as well. And that solution of yours is smart, I will try it right now -- of course a temporary solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Bad Idea Department:

```
program options >file 2>/dev/null | cat
```

It seems that bash won’t complain about segmentation faults in programs whose output is piped elsewhere. So just pipe your output anywhere. `cat` is a good choice, since it just echos the text it was sent. Or pipe to the null command, `:`, so you can put an emoji in your script:

```
program options >file 2>/dev/null |:
```

It should be obvious that this can hide other, more severe problems, and so you should fix the segmentation fault if at all possible.

Comment: Great bad idea! All I needed was a temporary patch. Maybe finally it is not forking in the background... I will file the bug on the related repository, and also will go through the code as soon as I can.

Comment: @retrography Thanks, although I kind of feel like you should both accept and downvote. :)

Comment: It should be noted that this works in bash and zsh, but not in ash, busybox sh, dash and mksh. (BTW, it isn't a "bad idea" for a test suite script to go with a program, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to fix the error.

The problem with hiding the error is twofold:

- The error might not be harmless.  Until you have identified the real cause, you cannot be sure.
- Anything that you implement to hide *this* error is liable to also hide *other* errors ... with may not exist yet, or may exist and not have manifested themselves yet.

---

> The program is not mine, and I have no idea how to fix it.

You need to discuss this with the developer / supplier.  Either get the source code and fix it yourself, or put pressure on them to fix it.  (There are various ways to do the latter ... depending on the nature of the software and support arrangements.)

---

If you really need a workaround, then take a look at how bash handles signals.  Based on the fact that redirection does not work, I suspect that what is happening is that bash is generating the message itself, and writing it to the console stream.  A plausible way to change this is to implement a custom signal handler for SIGSEGV in the bash script.  This approach has the advantage (over other "hacks") of being a bit selective.

Of course, there are other more "brutal" ways:

- Run the application in a subshell, and redirect the subshell's stderr in the main wrapper script.
- Pipe to `true` to suppress the signal reporting.  (See other answer.  I didn't know you could do that.)

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I am searching for a solution for the segfault as well: See the link in my comment above. My question is not only about the practical solution of the problem. I also want to know why and how despite the redirection I still get an error.

Comment: The program is open source. The source code is out there, and I am having a look at it right now, but I just needed a temporary fix. I just got one (above).

Comment: About piping to true: I didn’t know you could do that either. It was a typo for `|| true`. Now I’m perplexed. Your signal handler idea is probably better.

Comment: @S.Morgenstern - In terms of why "| true" works, my guess is that that bash is ignoring / not seeing the signal.  My guess is that it only sees signals from the last process in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @yellowantphil is hiding the output `Segmentation fault` in bash and zsh, but not in ash, dash, busybox sh and mksh. What works in all of the mentioned shells is redirection of shell's stderr using `exec`:

```
(exec 2>/dev/null
 program options >file 2>/dev/null)
```

Something which is not a part of the question, but useful in a test suite script sitting in the source code repository of a program, would be the subsequent testing if there was a segmentation fault, which would be done by testing if `$?` is equal to 139:

```
if [ $? -eq 139 ]; then
    # ...
fi
```