# Conceal a segmentation fault while keeping following commands aware of this incident

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521938/how-to-conceal-a-segmentation-fault-in-a-bash-script) asked about how to conceal a segmentation fault in a bash script and @yellowantphil provided a solution: pipe the output anywhere

Now I am looking through plenty of repositories handed in from my students. I need to check whether source codes in each repository could be compiled, and if so, whether the executable could work properly.

And I've observed that some of their executables end in failure with output 'segmentation fault'. Since I want to hide most details in my script, I prefer not showing any of this annoying output (and thus I found the question mentioned above). However, I still need to be aware that happens (to skip a loop). What should I do now?

A minimum reproduction of this problem:

1. Create any executable that causes 'segmentation fault'
2. Place it in a Bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

./segfaultgen >/dev/null 2>&1 | :

echo $?
```

With that `| :` (mentioned in @yellowantphil's answer), the following sentence shows the output `0`, which does not tell the truth. However error messages appear if `| :` is commented out. I've also tried appending `|| echo 1` before `| :`. It doesn't work as well :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a pipeline only fails if the right-side fails. Enable `pipefail` so the pipeline will fail if either command fails.

(It's a good option in general. I enable by default it in all of my scripts.)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail

./segfaultgen &>/dev/null | :
echo $?
```

Also, since you're using bash, `&>/dev/null` is shorter.

Comment: Good option indeed. However, error messages still appear. it seems that `| :` is useless under this circumstance ...

Comment: Now I fully understand why I/O redirecting does not work in this case. The error message "Segmentation fault" is generated in stderr of **the bash process** instead of stderr of the executable sub-process. It occurred to me that I could use catch the "segmentation fault" output if it _is_ in a sub-process. It is a good choice to save the output of the executable into a variable. Thus I tried `ret=$(./segfaultgen)` and then immediately `echo $?`. It works. However, there's no content in that variable `ret` if segmentation fault happens, even if the executable _does_ have output lines in stdout.