# Bash Script function not showing segmentation fault for C program in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I created a bash function to execute my C files, but it's not showing `segmentation fault` error when executed.

Bash function:

```sh
makex () {
    make $1 && "./$1"            
}
```

Output:

```
cc     example.c   -o example
```

Separating make and the command to execute the program results in the same output.

Creating a separate bash script in my bin folder results in the desired output:

```
cc     example.c   -o example
/home/user/bin/makex: line 28: 18981 Segmentation fault      ./$1
```

But I would like to keep this inside a function in a file that is in my PATH.

If there is a way to show the output exactly how it's showed when I directly execute it from the shell it would be perfect, because that is what I intended with this function:

```
$ make example && ./example
cc     example.c   -o example
[1]    19043 segmentation fault  ./example
```

Comment: Are you *expecting* a segmentation fault? Perhaps the build itself failed; `&&` will not execute the result if `make $1` does not succeed.

Comment: I created a bash script with the same code on my bin folder and executing it showed the segmentation fault error, so I think this is something to do with how functions work in bash.

Comment: You say the function is in a file in your PATH? How do you load it into your shell?

Comment: I am sourcing it from my .zshrc file. Maybe I am mistaking, but I think this means it is in my PATH.

Comment: `.zshrc` is not normally loaded by Bash. This is a Zsh file. If your question is about Zsh, please edit and retag accordingly.

Comment: A quick test suggests that Bash will print information about a segmentation fault in a program even if the program is run from a function (thankfully!).  How *exactly* are you defining and running the function.  [How to conceal a segmentation fault in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28521938/4154375) might contain relevant information.

Comment: If this is really a Zsh question please remove the 'bash' tag.  It's a booby trap.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using zsh. I am going to change my question. In fact when I execute the function from bash it showed the error.