# Bash script: ignore Segmentation fault

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a bash script that runs some bash lines after running an program. However, at the end of the program y, observe a segmentation fault:

```
...
[INFO] End of program.
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

If I run dmesg I can see:
[440123.420522] cosim.tv.exe[60620]: segfault at 1225000 ip 0000000000423f60 sp 00007ffeddadb3c8 error 4 in cosim.tv.exe[403000+22000]

My script bash looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

time ./cosim
echo "After execution"
```

However, as I found a segfault at the end of the run, the "After execution" does not print.
I tried several things, but none of them have worked. More specifically, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521938/how-to-conceal-a-segmentation-fault-in-a-bash-script).

I run the bash script with ./bash_script

Comment: Your `set -e` explicitly states that you want your script to exit when you've encountered a non-zero exit code (i.e. an error). If that isn't what you want, then remove `set -e`.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same behaviour after removing it. After trying some things, I left it there but didn't have it when I encountered this behaviour.

Comment: You may have `set -e` on your environment itself. Try running `set +e` before running your script, and see if that behavior persists. Otherwise, it'd help to write a quick example program producing a segfault that we can just paste+run to see it ourselves (since I'd have to do it myself to truly test your code).

Comment: In fact, using a [very short program that segfaults](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), I cannot reproduce the error you've specified (it shows the "After execution" line).

Comment: @Rogue `set -e` is not in the environment, it's not inherited.

Comment: @Rogue same thing still happens... I have a code with 
`echo "[INFO] Starting"`
`kill -11 $$`
`echo "End"`
 and the "End" never prints. Just the first print and the segmentation fault.

Comment: Well doing `kill -11 $$` (in-script) is a bit different from doing `time ./cosim` where `cosim` is throwing signal 11. The first will end the script outright, the latter will report the segmentation fault in the spawned child process and move on. Post your actual script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement as suggested [here](https://tecadmin.net/bash-error-detection-and-handling-tips-and-tricks/).

```bash
if time ./cosim; then
  echo "command succeeded"
else
  echo "command failed"
fi
```